# LVM Mount Point issue

Tags: lvm

I have a LVM volume named `/dev/mapper/centos-root`, centos being the volume group, root being a logical volume. It has the `fstab` entry below:

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root / xfs defaults 0 0
```

I have created two mount points to store tomcat data:

```
mkdir -p /opt/tcsserver
mkdir -p /sys_data/tcsserver
```

When I mount these 2 mountpoints to lvm and gave `mount|grep /dev/mapper/centos-root`:

```
mount /dev/mapper/centos-root /opt/tcsserver
mount /dev/mapper/centos-root /sys_data/tcsserver
mount -a
mount|grep /dev/mapper/centos-root
```

It shows the mountpoint perfectlty.

Can I have this added permanently like this below?

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root / xfs defaults 0 0
/dev/mapper/centos-root /opt/tcsserver xfs defaults 0 0
/dev/mapper/centos-root /sys_data/tcsserver xfs defaults 0 0
```

Will the above entry /etc/fstab work?
If I reboot will it come up?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have `/dev/mapper/centos-root` mapped to three different mount points— which I’m pretty sure doesn’t work.

But, if you mount `/dev/mapper/centos-root` to `/`, then `/opt/tcsserver` and `/sys_data/tcsserver` should also be part of that partition (unless you have something else mounted at `/opt` or `/sys_data`)— so you don’t have to and shouldn’t mount it three times.

In short, no. But just mounting your volume to `/` should be fine if you want everything on the same drive.

If what you want is to have `/opt/tcsserver` and `/sys_data/tcsserver` be the same, you can use a symlink:
`sudo ln -s /opt/tcsserver /sys_data/tcsserver`